# Is the use of this IEC filter proper for the this application?

Tags: filter

[Here](https://docs-emea.rs-online.com/webdocs/0e32/0900766b80e3230d.pdf) is the IEC module which has filters. The question is about using the IEC filter on the very left side in the below Figure.

Below from left to right there will be a power flow.
Right after the first IEC there will be line and neutral buses shown as circle nodes. From there I will be six AC mains access. I drew only three. Most of these will also have the same IEC modulesat their AC input. I hope the illustration explains the scanrio it well:

[image]

My worry is can a an IEC filter be used for multiple AC mains entries or even cascaded as shown? Or are they only to be used with a single unit such as a power supply?